# "Home" Menu item - Assign blank article to see homepage hits?

Tags: articles

I would like to see my homepage hits in my "Popular Articles" module in Joomla backend, so I created a blank article titled "Homepage" and assigned it to my "Home" menu item and have starred this menu item.

So now I can see the number of hits on my "Homepage" article.

Is this a good way of seeing my homepage hits? or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use Google Analytics for tracking such statistics. It can provide insights into many more like which browsers, countries etc.

Implementing Google Analytics is pretty easy.

- Sign up for Google Account
- Get the analytics JavaScript code from your Google Analytics site
- Add the code at the end of your page.

Most of the templates provides way to insert analytics code (or just your analytics account id to generate it themselves). If your template do not have this provision, you can use custom HTML module to insert code at the bottom of the page. It is a javascript code runs in background and will not show anything to your users.

Comment: Thanks. But to see the homepage count in my "Popular Articles" module. Is this an acceptable solution? Google analytics is best but for a simple interface for my client in the Joomla backend. Would assigning a blank "Homepage" article to the "Home" menu item be okay in your opinion?

Comment: That is okay if you just need total number of times the home page is loaded in your site lifetime. Hits will increment everytime someone visit the page no matter he visited earlier or not. And do not provide any day-wise stats.